# Sort by result of sub query in MySQL

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have one table which contains a record for all of the downloadable items and another table that contains a record of each download that includes the download date and the id of the item and the user who downloaded it.

When I get a list of items from the database I want the query to look up how many times an item has been downloaded and include this with the other item data.

Here's my SQL:

```
SELECT t1.*, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM tl_downloads 
    WHERE item_id = t1.id
    AND download_date > ?) 
AS downloads_count 
FROM tl_items AS t1 
ORDER BY downloads_count DESC
```

The above query works fine in the sense that I get an extra column in the results called 'downloads_count' which contains the correct count but it will not let me order by this value.

What do I need to do to be able to do order my results by the value returned in the sub query?

Let me know if you need any more info!

Edit - Sample data

```
tl_items                tl_downloads

id  name                id  item_id  download_date
1   Item 1              1   1        1385964000 
2   Item 2              2   1        1385964000
3   Item 3              3   3        1385964000
```

The results I expect would be:

```
Item 1 - Downloads 2
Item 3 - Downloads 1
Item 2 - Downloads 0
```

Thanks

Comment: Your example seems to work just fine actually: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3107f/2/0). But a join would probably be the better solution anyways.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

try,

```
SELECT  t1.*, 
        s.totalCount AS downloads_count 
FROM    tl_items AS t1 
        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT  item_id, COUNT(*) totalCount 
            FROM    tl_downloads 
            WHERE   download_date > ?
            GROUP   BY item_id
        )  s ON s.item_id = t1.id
ORDER   BY downloads_count DESC
```

Comment: Thanks. That seems to work fine without the download_date WHERE clause, but I'm getting the same problem as before when I include it.

Comment: can you give sample records and possibly with desired result? it makes helps me understand the problem more :D

Comment: No problem, I've provided an example in the original question. Thanks for helping

Comment: This provided me a 10X performance improvement over the standard join equivalent

Comment: You could try John Woo's answer, but using a RIGHT JOIN instead of the LEFT JOIN. 
When I used this query with LEFT JOIN my query took about 800ms, and with RIGHT JOIN less than 5 ms

Comment: How you can with 3 ?

Answer (score 1):

Expecting the 0 downloads to be included in the results and having download date constraint seems to be contradicting for me unless i am overlooking into it.

```
SELECT tt1.id, COUNT(tt2.id) AS DOWNLOAD_COUNT
FROM t1_items tt1
LEFT JOIN t1_downloads tt2 ON tt1.id = tt2.item_id
WHERE download_date > 1385963000 OR download_date IS NULL
GROUP BY tt1.id
ORDER BY DOWNLOAD_COUNT DESC
```

The above query will return the expected result.

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/29b39/13

Answer (score 0):

Not yet tested but another approach:

```
SELECT t1.* 
FROM tl_items AS t1 
ORDER BY 
(SELECT COUNT(*) totalCount
FROM tl_downloads 
WHERE item_id = t1.id
AND download_date > ? ORDER BY totalCount [desc])
```

Right? Maybe faster because of no joins.